# how to add onItemClick method in ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to add onItemClick method in listview of my app. I created a listview by using http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/
but unable add click method.
please suggest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
 yourList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {


        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you hava to use following method.

```
           list.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(getParent()));

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {


                        }


                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Before creating acticity make sure it is ListActicity. After that pass the selected value (item) to the below method.

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,
                                    long id) {
        selection.setText(items.get(position).toString());
    }
```

Comment: my acitivity does not extends ListActivity.

Comment: do you have List object inside your activity ?

Comment: Then you have to use onListItemClick method

Answer (score 0):

Set an [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) to your ListView.

Use the following code:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Put your custom code here
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int arg1,
                                    long id) {
        selection.setText(items.get(arg1).toString());
    }

Comment: While this may be an answer, you should attempt to explain what it is exactly that you are trying to achieve with this code. You should also wrap code inside a code block.